# Select optimal subintervals from array

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have an input array and I have to select an indefinite number of intervals from it so that the "profit" is maximal and I have exactly T elements selected in total, where T is given. Profit means the sum of all the elements of an interval, except for the first element. An interval can consist of a single element, meaning that the profit for such an interval is 0. The array may contain negative numbers. Apparently dynamic programming is the answer to this problem, but I cannot think of an efficient algorithm to solve it. This is homework, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Search for maximum subsequence sum problem, [here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/the-maximum-subsequence-problem) you will find a linear time solution. Bentley's ["Programming Pearls"](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls) gives several alternative algorithms and some history. The linear time solution is obvious in hindsight, but it took several tries by experts to come up with it...

Comment: Sorry @vonbrand I misunderstood my task. I have updated the question.

Comment: The new formulation is even simpler: Take the $T$ maximal elements of your array (leaving out the first one), and the one just before each contiguous range thus created.

Comment: For example, for the array [2000(pos 100) 1995(pos 101) 1999(pos 105) 1994(pos 106) 1998(pos 110) 1997(pos 115) 1996(pos 120)] if I want to extract 10 elements so that the profit is maximal, the optimal solution is [x 2000 1995] [y 1999 1994] [z 1998] [t 1997]. By using your advice, I would be selecting the largest five elements of the array and an extra element before each of them.